# 404: Unknown Message (Discord.py v0.16.12)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

`msg = await self.bot.get_message(channel, req["message_id"])`

channel and req["message_id"] are defined, the IDs are parsed as `str` (if `int`, then AttributeError would be raised) and the message is in the channel, yet the console output is this https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gp5vH.png. The bot has Administrator permission.

Comment: How are you defining `channel` and `req`?

Answer (score 0):

The error means that either the channel or the message was not found. It would be helpful to see how you are defining both the channel and the message in your code.

[Per the documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/v0.16.12/api.html#discord.Client.get_message), you should only need to pass the message_id as a string. I'm not sure what the req["message_id"] block does as I'm relatively new to this but it should be as simple as calling get_message(channel, message_id)

Comment: Channel is parsed as a direct string (`await self.bot.get_channel('ChannelIDhere')`). `req["message_id"]` (string) is stored in a json file that I access with `self.jsonfile` (`self.json = dataIO.read_json("JsonFilePathHere")`.

Comment: Have you done a print(channel.name + ' ' + req["message_id"]) to make sure they're both what you're expecting?